# Access denied for mysqldump command on forge with digitalocean

Tags: php, laravel, mysql

I'm running an artisan command that should backup my database, but I get this error:

> **mysqldump**: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'forge'@'45.65.33.154' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

This is the command:

```
exec('mysqldump -u '.$user.' -h '.$host.' -pmysql-pass '.$password.' forge > storage/files/'.$fileSql);
```

It's using the right username and password so I really can't see where the problem is. On my local machine it worked perfect. Of course I configured all the environment variables properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter is wrong for the password, it should be:

```
exec('mysqldump -u '.$user.' -h '.$host.' --password='.$password.' forge > storage/files/'.$fileSql);
```

You may need to grant access using this:

```
GRANT ALL ON yourdb.* TO theusername@mypc IDENTIFIED by 'the-password-goes-here';
```

Comment: Still not working. I tried many variations. When I did what you said it asked for a password so I gave it my password and it said unknown database password. Like it thought that the password was the database name.

Comment: Does your password variable contain a space?

Comment: Nope. Is the command wrong? Do I need a special permission for this?

Comment: you're using that same username/password to connect to mysql from that machine too?

Comment: Yes. And on the website itself everything is working well. I can access also sequel pro with the same credentials.

Comment: mmm, okay then you probably don't need to grant privileges.  what is the output of the generated string that exec uses? (mask any sensitive information, of course)

Comment: if you run the command manually from the shell, what happens? `mysqldump -u theUsername --password=thePassword -h blah forge > test.sql`

Comment: There are weird behaviors. When I use this command -         exec('mysqldump -u '.$user.' -h '.$host.' -p '.$password.' forge > storage/files/'.$fileSql);
I get:
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'U7867486784668' when selecting the database

Comment: there should NOT be a space between -p and the password. it needs to be `-pYourPassword` (no space) ... also, you just posted your password, feel free to delete your comment

Comment: I changed the numbers of course, thanks for caring. I ran your command and it said [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. When i do ls I see a file though

Comment: Okay then copy and paste the command you just ran and call it with exec() and it should work.

Comment: FYI, sending the password through `exec()` is not secure because if other users are on your server so they could see (this is true for some sort of shared hosting situation)... if no one else has access to your server it's not as big of a deal although important to be aware of.  If you have sensitive information that you are dealing with, I can post an alternative method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the only one with access. Well I ran the command, but got this error. Array to string conversion. Not my lucky day I guess.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of the output instead of an echo/print of the variable (post more of your code will help too).

Comment: What do you mean? To do it where? This is the only command that I have and then I send it to amazon s3.

Comment: $fileSql = date('m-d-y-h:i:s').'file.sql';
 Storage::disk('s3')->put('MyBackups/'.$fileSql, file_get_contents('storage/files/' . $fileSql));

This is all

Comment: What line is that error happening on? An array is getting converted to a string ... should be an easy fix.

Comment: Nothing is working. It doesn't make any sense. On my mamp it works perfect. The error is from the exec.

Comment: You need to inspect the value of the variable for where you have the error. You have an array somewhere that shouldn't be

Comment: Is there a way to see the value that is returned from the exec? How come on mamp I didn't have an array?

Comment: The error doesn't have anything to do with the return value of exec, it is likely an error in your PHP.

Comment: sorry was out eating lunch but back, read the documentation on exec at here, you can get the output pretty easily http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: another question is: do you have write access to the folder that mysqldump is trying to output to?  and it might be better to use an absolute path instead of a relative one if it is not generating the file dump

Comment: Yes I have. I upload all my files to that folder and it works fine. I tried just in case to output to the public folder but this array thing remains. I using now a route to dump it, but still the error doesn't help much. 
ErrorException in MimeType.php line 26:
Array to string conversion

Comment: I accepted it for your effort. I have a bug I guess somewhere in Laravel or the server.

Comment: Post the array string error as another question.  probably an easy fix.  I just found this for you, it may solve it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161606/laravel-s3-file-upload-mimetype-issue good luck!  otherwise post the contents of the MimeType.php file in the question you ask.